# A word meaning both masturbating and consoling oneself?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, popular-refrains

In Chinese, 自慰 means '(of a person, genderless) to masturbate', and it also means 'to console oneself'.

I took it as an extension of 'God helps whose who help themselves' for a certain period of time.

I just wonder in English, whether such a word exists?

Comment: The second part of the question is off topic; it is not about English but about ethics, philosophy, religion and other domains of human thought.

Comment: The term "practicing self-love" can be interpreted both ways. But this would not be a common double entendre.

Comment: Off-topic content removed from the question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what "console oneself" means here, as it can refer both to deep pain and to more trivial things. Merriam-Webster gives "to alleviate the grief, sense of loss, or trouble of" but it doesn't always refer to comforting bereavement or deep sadness, and can refer e.g. to consoling yourself with a beer after your football team loses. ("self-love" is good though, and can refer both to profound respect for oneself and a bit of pampering.)

Comment: I can't quite find the support for it, but I've heard **take care of yourself/myself** as a polite euphemism for masturbation, in addition to being (a) a literal recommendation to take care of yourself and (b) (with **yourself**) an idiomatic farewell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something that comes fairly close to the Chinese with two meanings, one general and one specific, is

**self-gratification** (n.)

> The act of pleasing oneself or of satisfying one's desires
> *especially*: the satisfying of one's own sexual urges [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-gratification)

> Self-satisfaction.
> (euphemistic)   Masturbation. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-gratification)

*Gratify* is close to *console*:

> **Console** and **gratify** are semantically related. Sometimes you can use
> "Console" instead a verb "Gratify".  ["Console and Gratify—Related
> words—mutual synonyms", Thesaurus.plus](https://thesaurus.plus/related/console/gratify)

> The failure I suffer reinforce my position. I feel sorry for myself,
> and this **self-gratification consoles** me for all the reverses I
> suffer. [Tzvetan Todorov; *Life in Common: An Essay in General
> Anthropology*, p.106](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Life_in_Common/Zlu-oWhO1L0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-gratification%20console&pg=PA106&printsec=frontcover)

> I don't care what the doctor, your friend, or anyone else tells you;
> this is against God. This is **self-gratification**, and God does not
> approve. This devil will tell you to **console/satisfy** yourself. So
> you want to replace your former boyfriend with your hand or some other
> object. [Evangelist Frances Elbert; *Single, Sanctified, and
> Satisfied*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Single_Sanctified_and_Satisfied/RscuEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-gratification%20masturbation%20console&pg=PT29&printsec=frontcover)

---

With reference to the OP's request for a *popular refrain*. When an adult warns a teen that "Too much masturbation will make you blind!", the most popular refrain is "Can I do it just until I need glasses?"

Comment: Talented friends from all over the world will always come together to help! : )